# Java: Efficient way to scan a folder for a particular file

Tags: java, performance

I am contacting an external services with my Java app.

The flow is as follow: ->I generate an XML file, and put it in an folder, then the service processes the file and return another file with the same name having an extension `.out`

Right now after I put the file in the folder I start with a loop, until I get that file back so I can read the result.

Here is the code:

```
        fileName += ".out";
        File f = new File(fileName);
        do
        {
            f = new File(fileName);
        } while (!f.exists());

        response = readResponse(fileName); // got the response now read it
```

My question comes here, am I doing it in the right way, is there a better/more efficient way to wait for the file?

Some info: I run my app on WinXP, usually it takes the external service less than a second to respond with a file, I send around 200 request per day to this services. The path to the folder with the result file is always the same.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why the creation of a new File object in each loop? The first instance of f should be fine. I recommend to put a Thread.sleep(100) in the loop - this will make the busy loop less busy (10 times per second). Another problem is that the file might not have written entirely in the moment you see it appear in the directory.

Comment: Thank you @ingo I have not though about the file being not written entirely.

Comment: @Adam, unfortunately, this is a stranger problem than one would think - all may work well on your developer machine but not at all in "production". The OS plays an important role here also, while unix will faithfully report the current file size, Windows may report 0 or some multiple of a power of 2 until the file is really closed from the other end. A nice trick in that case: let the other program write a file with yet another name and rename it when it is closed to the name you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason to recreate the `File` object. It just represents the file location, whether the file exists or not. Also you probably don't want a loop without at least a short delay, otherwise it'll just max out a processor until the file exists. You probably want something like this instead:

```
File file = new File(filename);
while (!file.exists()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

**Edit:** Ingo makes a great point in the comments. The file might not be completely there just because it exists. One way to guarantee that it's ready is have the first process create a second file after the first is completely written. Then have the Java program detect that second file, delete it and then safely read the first one.

Comment: +1 for Ingo's comment, really. I was going to post it as an answer until I realized it was already there in comments and at the end of yours. :) Note that while it's useful, it doesn't scale the best. Decent, but not the best If your files are quite small, and you do it a lot, you'll have a lot of extra overhead. Obviously, it's best to develop what's easy, profile, and optimize if necessary, and by that token it fits the bill for now.